# how to deal with files that have spaces in their names when passing it to a command

Tags: bash, shell

I'm new to bash and writing a shell script to add some metadata to music files and there are some spaces in filename

```sh
FFMPEG_TARGET_COMMAND="\"$INPUT_DIRECTORY\" $SOME_METADATA_ARG \"$OUTPUT_DIRECTORY\""

echo $FFMPEG_TARGET_COMMAND
> "/user/musicEx/Dream In Drive.mp3" \
-metadata album="soundtrack" \
-codec copy "/user/output/Dream In Drive.mp3"
```

```sh
ffmpeg -i $FFMPEG_TARGET_COMMAND
```

and I got "/user/musicEx/Dream: No such file or directory

But if I execute in shell by typing

```sh
ffmpeg -i "/user/musicEx/Dream In Drive.mp3" \
-metadata album="soundtrack" \
-codec copy "/user/output/Dream In Drive.mp3"
```

this will work

I wonder why. I've already escape the quote in $FFMPEG_TARGET_COMMAND. I tried to escape space character, but it didn't work too.

also, I tried to put all of them into one variable:

```sh
COMMAND="ffmpeg -i \"/user/musicEx/SCARLET NEXUS.mp3\"  -codec copy \"/user/output/SCARLET NEXUS.mp3\""
```

and I execute it by `$COMMAND`

So, in script, how to deal with files that have spaces in their names?

Comment: Don't put commands in variables if you don't need to; see [BashFAQ #50: "I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!"](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use bash arrays.

```
SOME_METADATA_ARGS=( -metadata album="soundtrack" )
ffmpeg_args=( "$INPUT_DIRECTORY" "${SOME_METADATA_ARGS[@]}" -codec copy "$OUTPUT_DIRECTORY" )
ffmpeg -i "${ffmpeg_args[@]}"
```

> how to deal with files that have spaces in their names when passing it to a command

Properly quote variable expansions to prohibit word splitting expansion. Check your scripts with shellcheck. It's not what you put in the variable, it's how you *use* the variable. Read https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020 and
https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050 .

No reason to SHOUT_THAT_MUCH. Prefer to use lower case variables for local non-exported variables.